# What is the meaning of "fan" and "purge his floor" in Matthew 3:12?

Tags: matthew, word-study, authorial-intent

What is meant by **fan** & **his floor** in in [Mathew 3:12](https://biblehub.com/matthew/3-12.htm)?

> Whose **fan** is in his hand, and he will throughly **purge** **his floor**, and
>   gather his wheat into the garner; but he will burn up the chaff with
>   unquenchable fire.

How is he going to **purge**?

Answer (score 1):

## Threshing wheat & a 'winnowing fan'

The "winnowing fan" is for blowing away the chaff while separating it from the wheat after it has been threshed. In ideal conditions, threshing wheat happens by tossing it while the natural wind carries away the chaff. If there is no wind, then a fan allows wheat to be winnowed in unfavorable conditions.

By having a fan, it means that he has the tools to separate the good from the bad, regardless of external conditions.

Cross-reference with:

*Judges 6:11* (NASB)

> [Gideon] was beating out wheat in a winepress [unfavorable conditions, having no wind] in order to save it from the Midianites.

Read more about:

- [Threshing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshing)
- [Winnowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnowing)
- [winnowing fan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winnowing_fan)
- [winnowing basket](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winnowing_basket)

Watch a video of threshing and winnowing the old way:

- [Threshing and Winnowing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iReC7WpveVs)
- [Winnowing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuYYI0DLgkA) (with a basket)
- Winnowing Fan (with modern fan)

Comment: This site [ostensibly] prefers longer answers. As posted your answer presumes a knowledge of what "thrashing" is in this context which is a bit circular. Can you please provide a source that explains the process? How does the agricultural practice relate to John's message? -1

Comment: Thanks, this was fun researching. I'm not one for unnecessary length, but "long answers" rather than "fill-in-the-blank" answers I totally agree with. This really isn't a question about "what is threshing", which would be off topic anyway. So, I leaned on heavy references because this should be general knowledge, but if all "shoulds" were so, we wouldn't be here. :-) Thanks and I hope you like it. Tell me if you have any problem.

Answer (score -1):

the wind is that wind of the day of Pentecost (acts 2:2) this Holy Ghost Power saturates the righteous, making them more righteous and condemns the refusing unrighteous when they refuse to confess while under conviction of their sins.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE. Please take [the site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) in order to better understand its purpose. Your post does not answer the question and is likely to be removed.

Comment: If you think this does answer the question, please [edit] to explain in more detail.